# Can we modify or customise the data structure(for e.g. tree, Linked List etc.) of Java object(s)?

Tags: java, object, data-structures, tree

I recently came across header nodes concept in tree & linked-list data structures & while practising the same in Java I felt if it's possible to have my reference variable as a header node by default for the object I'm creating via 'new' keyword.

As we know currently when we create any object by means such as 'new' keyword, factory methods, cloning etc. we basically make the reference variable as Root node & the instance variable(s) are akin to child nodes[which if are objects would of course increase the length of linked-list(in case of single instance variable) or level of tree(in case of multiple instance variables)].

Since header nodes provide advantages like no need of null checks, I feel it would be great to integrate it with my application development. However I'm unable to figure out how to override the existing behaviour of JVM/JRE which creates the objects.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can't override the behavior of how it creates objects.  Can you explain more clearly what you want?  A header node is nothing more than another small structure, which could be a separate instance or just integrated (LinkedList has this information as fields, like first node, last node, size, so in that respect the LinkedList itself is the header node).

Comment: Thanks @john16384 for guidance. My intention was to override JVM functionality of creating objects in heap memory(to change the data structure it chooses that time) as I read sentinel nodes(like header node) in trees & linked-list help in performing the  boundary/edge tests. So, is there any alternate way to have these tests automated (apart from having it implemented in constructor methods since there can be some common tests for all classes but each and every class may not be related to each other via inheritance)?

Comment: You are thinking in a way that makes no sense for Java.  You donot have to worry about how it allocates things in the heap.  Can you actually give an example of what you want (in C code or otherwise)?  You can create any structure you want in Java, but you may need to write it yourself (instead of using standard classes like LinkedList).  Tests in constructors can be delegated to any static method if you fear repeated code, or you can have factories that construct first, test, and reject if they're not correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you clarify your question? Are you asking how to override the way Java creates objects? If so, you can't override it. When initializing a Linked List, the first node that is pushed to the linked list becomes the head node. The next node that is pushed becomes linked to the head node. Then, each node that is pushed to the linked list becomes linked to the previous node.

When creating a custom linked list, you could implement a function that pushes the elements in ascending order, so that the list is sorted. So, that's one way you could change the way a Linked list is created. However, you can't override the process of using the 'new' keyword, factory methods, or cloning to actually create the object.

Comment: My intention was to perform common boundary/edge tests for each and every object, is there any alternate way to have these tests automated (apart from having it implemented in constructor methods because then I'll have to code those same tests for many classes since each and every class is not related via inheritance)?